# Change all photo durations at once in iMovie 10.1.1

Tags: imovie

I'm doing a quick project in iMovie but it's anything less than quick! I have imported all the pictures I want, no videos/clips. I have added them into the project and want them ALL to be the same length. I can edit them individually but not all at the same time. How can i do this?

There was a suggestion on another site:
Window->Show Adjustments Bar

ALAS! This option does not exist in my copy I guess. I click Window and Show Adjustments Bar is not present. I want to change them all at once! This will help ALL future projects.

Answer (score 15):

Click EDIT
Select In Movie
Photos

Then go to "i" top right and select time.  Seems to be min limit of 0.1sec

Do the same for transitions to remove.